# what is ::class php in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Sorry for weak English!
I know `ClassName::Class` will return class name with namespace.
but why in laravel used this when class name is written with namespace?
like:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class
```

I'm confused about it!
Can someone tell me what is ::Class exactly?

Comment: As discussed in the duplicate, the most important thing to me is the IDE support for both autocompletion and linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

> Using that ::class syntax allows you to declare a class without
>   passing it as a string. When they update ide's it will help to auto
>   fill namespaces which can't be done with a string.

**Source Information:**

Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class. This is particularly useful with namespaced classes.

Example #10 Class name resolution

```
<?php
namespace NS {
    class ClassName {
    }

    echo ClassName::class;
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
NS\ClassName
```

Note:

> The class name resolution using ::class is a compile time
>   transformation. That means at the time the class name string is
>   created no autoloading has happened yet. As a consequence, class names
>   are expanded even if the class does not exist. No error is issued in
>   that case.

**Source Link** :: [Php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)

Comment: useful question specially the last point